# #Flutter Floating navigation bar where bottom elements are visible

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to make a package where I can achieve this:

[image]

But this is my progress. Still there is a white background.
Here is the link to the package
https://github.com/dinurymomshad/flutter_navigation_dot_bar (it is a forked repo)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `extendBody: true,` inside your `Scaffold()`.

Answer (score 0):

try to add stack as body and add bottomNav as Positioned widget